# Special Char in SSID with wpa_supplicant causing issue (Debian hdmi stick)

Tags: linux, debian, driver, wifi, ssid

I have a problem I can connect in wireless with `wpa_suppli`.

Can't on some network, but I need to connect on a network where the SSID contain a "é" and it won't work and I don't understand why, when I do: `iwlist scan` I get the ssid in this way:

```
Cell 01 - Address: 00:22:07:59:K5:C9
                    ESSID:"t\xC3\xA9test"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

So I try some thing like add a P before my SSID like :

```
network={
    ssid=P"t\xC3\xA9st"
    psk="My password"
}
```

also

```
network={
    ssid=P"tést"
    psk="My password"
}
network={
    ssid="t\xC3\xA9st"
    psk="My password"
}
network={
    ssid="tést"
    psk="My password"
}
```

but none of this work,

Whent I try to launch the wpa_supplicant here's the error I get :

```
root@MSDEV264:~# /sbin/wpa_supplicant -i p2p0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Could not re-add multicast membership for vendor events: -2 (No such file or directory)
p2p0: Trying to associate with 00:22:07:59:f5:c9 (SSID='t\xC3\xA9st' freq=2412 MHz)
p2p0: Association request to the driver failed
```

then it continue in an infinite loop of :

```
p2p0: Trying to associate with 00:22:07:59:f5:c9 (SSID='t\xC3\xA9st' freq=2412 MHz)
p2p0: Association request to the driver failed
```

My locale are correctly set to UTF-8 .

If you have some ideas, Thank you in advance. I've add more precision about the error message.

Comment: uname -r return this :
`root@MS264:~# uname -r
3.0.36+`
if it can help

Answer (score 5):

For special characters in SSID/PSK use hex string

```
network={
    ssid=00010203
    psk=6173632761736361737363c3a461
}
```

[Source](http://www.cs.upc.edu/lclsi/Manuales/wireless/files/wpa_supplicant.conf)

**Update:**

use wpa_cli:

```
wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid '"12345678'üČ\"\\"'
```

Comment: How can I convert string to HEX?

Comment: For SSID: `echo -n "mySsidWithUTF8" | tr -d "\n" | od -A n -t x1 | tr -d " " | tr -d "\n"`. For psk see my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1544279/195933

Comment: in your update, what's the target password? eg. `"12345678'üČ\"\\"` or `12345678'üČ"\ ` or ...?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to get the ssid name correctly by finding first the bss (ex: 11:1a:aa:ff:ff:ff)

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Or

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results
```

Then use that bss in:

> wpa_cli bss 11:1a:aa:ff:ff:ff | grep ssid

And use that name in the wpa_supplicant conf

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy the example - this is what I got after pasting into the terminal running wpa_cli:

> set_network 12 ssid '"12345678'\303\274\304\214"\360\237\246\204\"'
> FAIL

This works:

set_network 6 ssid "12345678\303\274\304\214""
(with 214\ " " at the end without spaces)

with the wpa_cli program. I can't seem to type in any foreign characters or symbols - just the HEX representation.

Comment: I'm a developer of a device that will have to connect o any Wifi network available and must be able to deal with all foreign characters. If the Wifi network is seen in scan_results, why do I get errors when connecting to it?